# HTML 5 admin area editing

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar, admin

I'm trying to create a page that displays a progress bar .

The idea is to have a client page with a bar that starts at 0. Every time a user completes a challenge , an admin can go to their admin page , click a button and add 10% onto that bar. This would then update on the client page.

So far I have a progress bar which i can update from the client page , which isnt that good.

I was trying to use the couch cms , but that failed.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a "progress bar" in the traditional sense.  Rather, the elements which make up the "progress bar" are just dynamically served from the server-side code.

Consider a database table which stores this data.  Something as simple as:

```
User | Progress
---------------
1    | 30
2    | 50
3    | 10
```

And so on, just storing the "progress" for each user.  In your admin interface, there would be controls to increase or decrease these values.  All they do is update the database.  They don't update the "page" because that's a separate concern.

Then the user page simply reads the value for that user when it's loaded and renders some UI element accordingly.  If you use any sort of "progress bar" plugin for the UI then I imagine the numeric value from the database would just be used as the current state of that progress bar.  For example, if you use the jQuery UI progress bar, you'd initialize it with the given value:

```
$('#progressbar').progressbar({
  value : 30
});
```

How you emit that value to the page depends entirely on your server-side code.  In ASP.NET MVC for example it might be something like this:

```
$('#progressbar').progressbar({
  value : @Model.UserProgress
});
```

Of course, that's just an example.  I don't know what server-side technology you're using (if any).

The user page wouldn't need any way to change the progress bar itself, they'll see the current state the next time they visit the page.  (Assuming I understand your use cases correctly.)

Comment: Thats actually spot on . I was thinking of using as.net because it seemed easier . Could you point me to some tutorials that show me how to do the things you mentioned like reading from a database / the admin controls.

Comment: @StefanLazic: I'm sure there are many such tutorials.  http://www.asp.net is a good place to start, it has lots of walkthroughs and tutorials: http://www.asp.net/mvc